# How do I connect to and use a transparent proxy using Linux sockets in C?

Tags: linux, sockets, winsock, transparentproxy

I'm trying to write a program that connects to a transparent proxy using Linux sockets (which should easily port to Winsock) in C. I've scoured the internet to no avail.

To be specific I am not writing a transparent proxy, only connecting to it.

How can this be done?

Comment: Err.... isn't the point of a transparent proxy that you *don't* have to explicitly connect to it?

Comment: The question still stands; how do I utilize a transparent proxy using the Linux socket API?

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question."*

Comment: Is connecting to a transparent proxy using Linux sockets not specific enough?